# keyboard shortcut to switch between windows within an application

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

Is there a keyboard shortcut, or can I somehow bind a shortcut, to switch between windows within an application (similar to <kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> on macOS)?

Ideally, I'd like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to be unaffected or to be rebound to switch between applications (not between windows).

Comment: In Windows, this key is CTRL + F6 (FYI for context on what is being asked).

Answer (score 340, accepted):

The existing shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>key above TAB</kbd>

Depending on your keyboard *key above TAB* could be <kbd>§</kbd>, <kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>º</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>²</kbd>, etc.

Comment: On other keyboards the key is also known as '~' or '`' key.

Comment: Awesome, that works. On my uk laptop, it's printed with backtic"`", (not sign?)"¬" and broken bar, but works as described.

Comment: On my azerty french keyboards, the key above the Tab key is a small "2" and it works.

Comment: This is nice when you're already in the app of the window. If you're in another window, you need to to use the regular alt+tab and wait on the multiple window app to see the multiple windows of that app.

Comment: Needless to say that what I wrote above is a slow way of switching between windows. Don't know why Ubuntu copied this bad behavior from Apple :(

Comment: I'm talking about Ubuntu 14.04 but this behavior goes back quite a long time now. Sadly. IMO.

Comment: In german layout it is `ALT` + `^` which is right above the TAB key

Comment: May differ for Xubuntu, where IIRC default key combo didn't work and I had to set it in Window Manager.

Comment: In Spanish layout it is `Alt+º`, and as @rubo77 said, it's above the `Tab` key.

Comment: Since last month I am working using mouse, Today I strike and searched it. Unfortunately that key is just above on `TAB`.  I just love you man. <3

Comment: Can this be modified?

Comment: Yes it can be modified, use compiz > Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Switcher > Key to flip windows in the switcher. It worked on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I find it no longer works this way (Ubuntu 20.10). It seems now only to switch to the file explorer.

Answer (score 15):

You should press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the key just above the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

From comments, this is the key you should be pressed by keyboard layout:

- Spanish <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>º</kbd>.
- German <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd>.
- Azerty french <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>²</kbd>.

In others may be <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>§</kbd> o <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (I don't know from where they come)

Answer (score 7):

If someone looking to bind to a different key combination, It can be done in settings.
On Ubuntu 18.04.3, go to

> `settings` > `Devices` > `Keyboard` >

Under `Keyboard Shortcuts` scroll to `Navigation` and click on `Switch windows of an application` change the key combination and set it. I have changed mine to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>)

Comment: In my case the shortcut was set to `Super+\``, but `Alt+\`` was also working. But I had the `\`` symbol also mapped for another key, not that one above tab, and the shortcuts didn't work with this key. I just manually remapped the binding in settings to `Super+\`` (the same as default) and the another key started working too

Answer (score 6):

1. To go to the active application: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>
2. If multiple instance of the selected applications are opened and you want to navigate among them use : <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

Comment: same as accepted answer

Comment: What's nice here is how the two work together. Want a specific window of a different application? Press `alt` and keep it down, `tab` until that application is highlighted, then press `[key above tab]` until it gets the right window, then release `alt` and you're there

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> switches between panes or windows in Ubuntu applications, such as Nautilus.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> will also sometimes switch between windows (or tabs), for example in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Opt + Tab will switch between windows of different applications running. 
CTRL + Tab will switch between windows within the same application.

At least this is how it is running Ubuntu on my Macbook.

Answer (score 0):

This differs in various keyboard layouts, but usually it is the key right above the TAB key.

In the german and spanish layout it is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>°</kbd>

This is quite handy, this way you can easily access both switches.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to hover over the icon of the program in the sidenav/side bar of ubuntu and scroll using the scroll wheel of the mouse, this way will make you go through all the open instances of the program, it would be ideal if you have only two, helpful if you have more than two. I use it with vscode usually because I always have more than one open.

Comment: when someone is asking about a keyboard shortcut, it's because they don't want to move their hands off of the keyboard, not because they don't know of another way to achieve what they want to do.  at least that's why I would ask about a keyboard shortcut (and why my googling led me to this page)