# How to switch between two windows of the same application using keyboard

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have opened Chrome browser in Ubuntu: a normal window and an incognito window.
I want to switch from the normal window to the incognito window using the keyboard.
I have tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but it switches to new windows (i.e. from Chrome browser to File Manager).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is used for shifting between tabs in the current window (i.e. tabs in Chrome Normal window).

Please do let me know if there is any shortcut for it.

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut for this is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Key above Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Key above Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the short key to switch between different windows of same application.

- Use `Alt + F6` to switch.
- We also can use `Ctrl + Alt`, `downward arrow` and `left or right` keys

But I do prefer `Alt + F6`

Answer (score 0):

Please see below Link.  As per this link it is the Alt and the key just above the Tab key.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en

&

[keyboard shortcut to switch between windows within an application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372398/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-windows-within-an-application)

Comment: I've tried all but not working...